# Display Arabic text in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, internationalization, arabic

I have my GDB where names for a few fields in feature class is written in Arabic. When I label them, it is displaying the labels but unable to understand the text as it is symbolized/coded.

Can anyone suggest how to add Arabic text and display the labels properly to make them readable?

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot of what you're getting, and include information about what version of ArcGIS you're using? Here's [a labeled example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Le34I.png) that works fine on my end.

Comment: I Am using ArcGIS 10.2. how can i upload screenshot to this question?

Comment: OK here are my tips first copy the text from attribute table and past it to Excel to see text is OK. If it is OK then install Arabic support on your operating system. Now this dependent on which operating system you are using. For Windows 7 see this link http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/install-or-change-a-display-language